# What's wrong with this transformation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have the equation $\tan(x) = 2\sin(x)$ and I'd like to transform it in this way:
$$\tan(x) = 2\sin(x)
\Longleftrightarrow
\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = 2\sin(x)
\Longleftrightarrow
\sin(x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)
\Longleftrightarrow
\sin(x) = \sin(2x)$$
But I'm getting a wrong result so I suppose that I can't do it in this way. Why?

EDIT: 
This is my solution:
$$\tan(x) = 2\sin(x)
\Longleftrightarrow
\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = 2\sin(x)
\Longleftrightarrow
\sin(x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)
\Longleftrightarrow
\sin(x) = \sin(2x)
\Longleftrightarrow
\sin(2x) - \sin(x) = 0
\Longleftrightarrow
2\cos(\frac{3x}{2})\sin(\frac{x}{2}) = 0
\Longleftrightarrow
\cos(\frac{3x}{2}) = 0 \vee \sin(\frac{x}{2}) = 0$$

Proper solution is $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2} \vee \sin(x) = 0$

Comment: I think he is trying to solve this equation; I am proceeding on that assumption.

Comment: You can do it this way. The only possible problem is $\cos x = 0$, but then $\sin x = \pm 1 \neq 0 = \sin (2x)$, so that introduces no spurious solutions. Probably some simple calculation error elsewhere.

Comment: You are correct that the equation $\tan(x)=2\sin(x)$ is equivalent to $\sin(x)=\sin(2x)$.  You have not said, though, what you are doing next.  How are you getting your solutions?

Comment: Um, yeah... You should have the same solutions on both sides. The critical points $\cos(x)=0$ aren't solutions to the RHS, so there aren't any extraneous solutions.

Comment: So I second mweiss's comment; you made a mistake in computing the solutions to $\sin(x)=\sin(2x)$.

Comment: So ... instead of saying "I get a wrong result" you should tell us that wrong result and how you get it.

Comment: @GEdgar I've just updated my post.

Comment: In the second line of your chain of implications, where did $3x/2$ come from all of a sudden? The previous was $\sin(2x)-\sin(x)=0$, and now suddenly there's $3x/2$? This step certainly is not as careful as the others preceding...

Comment: @tdudzik Among all your steps, not every step is a bi-implication. In particular, the second step is only valid if $\cos(x) \ne 0$.

Comment: @paulgarrett - tdudzik is making use of the identity $$2\cos \theta\sin\phi = \sin(\theta+\phi) - \sin(\theta-\phi)$$ with $\theta = 3x/2$ and $\phi = x/2$

Comment: @Nayuki - $\cos x = 0$ is not a solution to the original equation, nor the transformed equation, so this is not a problem.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, ok, and/but I more more largely baffled by the whole route taken, is the reason for my question. E.g., why not just take out the factor $\sin(x)$ in the first place, to have $\sin(x)\cdot (\cos x - 1)=0$ or whatever? All mysterious to me...

Comment: @paulgarrett That would certainly have been much quicker, and reduced the OP's confusion, but this was how OP figured out how to turn it into a multiplicative rather than additive problem.

Comment: The only true mistake here was to think that either your "solution" or the "proper solution" are solutions. They are only waypoints to the actual solution, which is the set of values of $x$ that make the original equation true.

Comment: @paulgarrett - certainly a much easier method, but this question was "what is wrong with this method?", not "how could I have done this more easily?". And there is actually nothing wrong with the path he chose, other than failing to go all the way.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, indeed. But, methodologically, sometimes there's a "meta" error of taking too long a path... I guess that was not the intended question here, no.

Comment: "Why is this transformation illegal?"
I wasn't aware that any transformations were against the law.

Comment: @Shufflepants: If you do division by something that could be zero, that is **illegal** and punishable by contradiction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no problem. Your solution is correct, and the other solution is correct. But you need to do a little work to see that they give the same answers:

- $\cos \frac {3x}2 = 0$ gives $x = \frac{(2k+1)\pi}3:\ x \in \{\pm \frac{\pi}3, \pm\pi,\pm \frac{5\pi}3, \pm \frac{7\pi}3, \pm 3\pi, \ldots\}$
- $\sin \frac {x}2 = 0$ gives $x = 2k\pi:\ x \in  \{0, \pm 2\pi, \pm 4\pi, \ldots\}$

while

- $\cos x = \frac 12$ gives $x =\pm \frac{\pi}3 + 2k\pi:\ x \in \{\pm \frac{\pi}3, \pm \frac{5\pi}3, \pm \frac{7\pi}3, \ldots\}$
- $\sin x = 0$ gives $x = k\pi:\ x \in  \{0, \pm\pi, \pm 2\pi, \pm 3\pi,\pm 4\pi, \ldots\}$

Comparison of the values shows that the same ones are in both lists.

Answer (score 8):

You must disregard all points where $\cos(x) = 0$.  These are outside of the domain of the initial expression you have on the left-hand side.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but when I do this result will be correct?

Comment: @tdudzik The result will be correct if there are any solutions where $\cos(x)\ne0$.

Answer (score 7):

The solutions to $\sin(\frac{x}{2})=0$ or $\cos(\frac{3x}{2})=0$ are given by $$\frac{x}{2} = \pi k \text{ or } \frac{3x}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k, k \in \mathbb Z,$$ which can be rewritten as $$x = 2\pi k \text{ or } x = \frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{2\pi}{3}k, k \in \mathbb Z.$$

The solutions to $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ or $\sin(x)=0$ are given by $$x = \frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi k, \frac{5\pi}{3}+2\pi k, \pi k, k \in \mathbb Z.$$ These are the same sets of points.

Comment: Beat me by 5 seconds...

Comment: @PaulSinclair Hah, that does happen. +1 to you. :)

Answer (score 3):

Equations $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = 2\sin x$ and $\sin x =2\sin x\cos x$ are indeed equivalent since for $\cos x = 0$ you have $\sin x =\pm 1$, which doesn't give solution for the second equation.

So, to solve it, we have that either $\sin x = 0$ or $\cos x = \frac 1 2$, thus solutions are given by $x = 2k\pi$, $x = \pi + 2k\pi$, $x = \pm\frac\pi 3 + 2k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.

To summarize, there is no error in your manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

To solve, set $\sin(x) = \sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$.  Subtracting and factoring you get
$$\sin(x)(2\cos(x) - 1) = 0.$$
This happens if $x = 0, \pi, \pi/3, 5\pi/3$.  None of these is a solution to $\cos(x) = 0$, so they all work.

Comment: I understand your solution but could you glance at my updated question and tell me what's wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your solution.

First, the transformation $$ 
\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = 2\sin x \iff \sin x = 2\sin x \cos x
$$ is false.  The correct inference is $$ 
\left( \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = 2\sin x \text{ and } \cos x \neq 0 \right) \text{ or } \cos x = 0  \iff (\sin x = 2\sin x \cos x \text{ and } \cos x \neq 0) \text{ or } \cos x = 0 
$$ otherwise, going to the left, you divide by zero, and going to the right, you (might) delete the content of your equation by multiplying both sides by zero.  (The hazards are $0 = 0 \implies 0 x = 0 y \not\Rightarrow x = y$ and $x \neq y \not\Rightarrow 0x \neq 0y \implies 0 \neq 0$.)  Starting with either of your equations, you infer the entire other side of the more complicated bi-implication.  Since this can introduce spurious solutions, all solutions must be checked in the original equation at the end of the process.

This suggests a general rule:  Do not cancel.  Instead subtract and factor.  This highlights your second error.  From $$
\sin x = 2 \sin x \cos x \text{,}
$$ subtract and factor to get $$
(1-2\cos x)\sin x = 0 \text{.}
$$  The first factor gives your $\cos x = \frac{1}{2}$.  The second factor gives $\sin x = 0$.  (This is because the product of several things being zero means at least one of them is.)

By proper inference, you should have \begin{align*}
    &      &  \tan x &= 2 \sin x \\
    &\iff  &  \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} &= 2 \sin x \\
    &\iff  &  \sin x &= 2 \sin x \cos x \text{ or } \cos x = 0 \\
    &\iff  &  (1-2\cos x)\sin x &= 0 \text{ or } \cos x = 0 \\ 
    &\iff  &  \cos x &= \frac{1}{2} \text{ or } \sin x = 0 \text{ or } \cos x = 0 \text{.}
\end{align*}  Checking for spurious solutions, all solutions of $\cos x = \frac{1}{2}$ and all solutions of $\sin x = 0$ are solutions of the given equation, but none of the solutions of $\cos x = 0$ are, so the final solution is $\cos x = \frac{1}{2} \text{ or } \sin x = 0$.

Somewhat shorter uses subtract and factor earlier, avoiding the complicated bi-implication altogether: \begin{align*}
    &      &  \tan x &= 2 \sin x \\
    &\iff  &  \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} &= 2 \sin x \\
    &\iff  &  \left( \frac{1}{\cos x} - 2 \right) \sin x &= 0 \\
    &\iff  &  \frac{1}{\cos x} - 2 &= 0 \text{ or } \sin x = 0 \\
    &\iff  &  \frac{1}{\cos x} &= 2 \text{ or } \sin x = 0 \\
    &\iff  &  \cos x &= \frac{1}{2} \text{ or } \sin x = 0 \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: This strikes me as super confused. Your sequence of bi-implications after "By proper inference, you should have" are not correct at all; it should be "and $\cos x \neq 0$" after you've multiplied by $\cos x$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein : I could have "$(\sin x = 2 \sin x \cos x \text{ and } \cos x \neq 0) \text{ or } \cos x = 0$", exactly as in the prior bi-implication, but I invite you to show me how the set is changed by this complication.  We cannot have either of $\cos x = 1/2 \text{ and } \cos x = 0$ or $\sin x = 0 \text{ and } \cos x = 0$.  So the "$\dots \text{ and } \cos x \neq 0$" changes the set not at all.

Comment: What??? This is basic logic; "$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = 2 \sin x$" is equivalent to "$\sin x = 2 \sin x \cos x \text{ and } \cos x \neq 0$", ***not*** to "$\sin x = 2 \sin x \cos x \text{ or } \cos x = 0$" as you've said. I don't know why you nested the conditions on $\cos$; did you really misunderstand me that badly?

Comment: Saying "... or $\cos x = 0$ introduces all solutions to $\cos x = 0$ to the set, none of which are solutions to the previous equation.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein : "Since this can introduce spurious solutions, all solutions must be checked in the original equation at the end of the process."

Comment: You apparently have a shaky understanding of what $\iff$ means.